# Positioning of label text in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making line graphs using `geom_smooth` and labelling it using `geom_dl`. The lines also have `geom_points` as an additional display. The texts are positioned on the points and I want the text to be positioned on the tails of the smooth lines. My code is given as below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

ggplot(gedu5, aes(x = Year, y = gedu, colour = Country, group = Country)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), se = FALSE)+
  geom_point(stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Country), method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 1)) +
  labs(title = "Government expenditure on education, total (% of GDP)", cex.main = 2.5) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Region, 2, scales="free")
```

The Image it renders is given as below. As you can see in the image
[image] that labels are actually  pegged on the points and not on the lines. I want to stick the labels to the lines and not to the points.

The data for the above image is here:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 1998L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L), Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
"Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
"Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
"Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", 
"Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
"Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
"Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", 
"Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "Bhutan", "India", "India", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", 
"India", "India", "India", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", 
"Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", 
"Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", 
"Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Maldives", "Nepal", 
"Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
"Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", 
"Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
"Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
"Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
"Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", 
"Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", 
"Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", 
"Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", 
"Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", "Sri_Lanka", 
"World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", 
"World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", 
"World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "World", "South_Asia", 
"South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", 
"South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", 
"South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", 
"South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "South_Asia", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Sub.Saharan_Africa", 
"Sub.Saharan_Africa", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", 
"Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", 
"Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", 
"Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", 
"Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", "Middle_income", 
"Middle_income", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", "Central_Europe_and_the_Baltics", 
"Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", 
"Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", 
"Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", 
"Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", "Euro_area", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", 
"Middle_East_North_Africa", "Middle_East_North_Africa", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", "Latin_America_Caribbean", 
"Latin_America_Caribbean", "North_America", "North_America", 
"North_America", "North_America", "North_America", "North_America", 
"North_America", "North_America", "North_America", "North_America", 
"North_America", "North_America", "North_America", "North_America", 
"North_America", "North_America", "North_America", "North_America", 
"North_America", "North_America", "Low_income", "Low_income", 
"Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", 
"Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", 
"Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income", 
"Low_income", "Low_income", "Low_income"), gedu = c(3.5, 3.8, 
3.7, 3.3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.5, 3.5, 2.6, 
3.5, 3.7, 3.3, 4.2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2, 2.1, 1.9, 2.1, 
2.1, 2.2, 2, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 2.5, 5.5, 5.7, 
5.5, 5.7, 6.2, 6.8, 6.4, 7.1, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.6, 4, 4.7, 5.5, 
5.6, 5.9, 7.3, 6.8, 7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.3, 4.2, 4, 3.6, 3.4, 3.2, 
3.1, 3.2, 3.1, 3.3, 3.4, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 5.8, 
5.5, 4.9, 4.7, 5.8, 5.3, 4.7, 5, 4.7, 4.4, 4.5, 5.8, 4.1, 3.5, 
3.8, 3.8, 3.5, 4.4, 4.1, 4.1, 2.9, 2.9, 3, 3.7, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 
3.4, 3.6, 3.5, 3.8, 4.7, 3.6, 3.8, 3.8, 3.5, 4, 3.7, 4.4, 5.5, 
2.6, 2.6, 1.8, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 2.6, 2.6, 2.8, 2.6, 2.3, 
2.2, 2.1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.9, 3, 5.2, 6.6, 7.3, 7.5, 7.2, 
6.6, 5.7, 4.7, 3.7, 2.8, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.5, 1.6, 1.9, 2.2, 3.5, 
2.8, 4.2, 4.2, 3.9, 4, 4, 4.1, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.7, 4.5, 
4.3, 4.3, 4.6, 4.6, 4.7, 4.5, 4.5, 3, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3.1, 
2.6, 3.2, 2.9, 2.6, 2.8, 2.6, 3.4, 2.8, 2.4, 3, 3.1, 3, 3.5, 
2.9, 3.3, 3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9, 
3.8, 3.9, 4.1, 4, 4.3, 4.5, 3.9, 4.5, 4.1, 4.1, 3.6, 3.7, 3.4, 
3.6, 3.5, 3.9, 3.9, 3.6, 4, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.3, 
4.2, 4.4, 5, 4.6, 4.9, 5.1, 5.2, 5.1, 4.9, 4.8, 4.7, 4.6, 4.8, 
5, 4.8, 4.6, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.8, 4.7, 4.7, 4.5, 4.8, 4.6, 5.2, 
5.3, 5.1, 5, 5, 4.8, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5, 5.3, 5.3, 4.9, 
4.8, 4.8, 6.2, 6.3, 6.3, 6.2, 6.1, 6, 5.4, 5.6, 4.3, 5.2, 4.5, 
4.7, 4.5, 4.4, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.5, 3.3, 3.8, 3.8, 3.8, 
3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 4.6, 5.3, 4.7, 4.4, 4.4, 5, 5.3, 
4.9, 4.5, 4.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.6, 
4.8, 5.4, 5.3, 5.3, 4.9, 5, 5, 4.9, 5, 3.2, 3.2, 2.9, 3.3, 3.4, 
3.2, 3.1, 3.1, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.1, 3.3, 3.8, 
3.1, 3.5), Region = c("South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", "South Asia", 
"South Asia", "South Asia", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", 
"Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region", "Region"
)), row.names = c(NA, -360L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: xiexie! for improving query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `geom_dl` uses the value of `gedu` in your dataset and not the fitted values computed by `geom_smooth`.

I tried

1. passing `stat="smooth"` to `geom_dl` which resulted in no labels appearing on the plot
2. adding labels at the endpoints manually using `stat_smooth` with `geom="text"` which however did not work

Therefore the only solution I could figure out is to compute the fitted values manually which can then be mapped on `y` in `geom_dl`. For computing the fittes values I

1. `tidyr::nest` the df by `Country` and `Region`
2. use `purrr::map` and `broom::augment` to do the estimation and to get the fitted values
3. `tidyr::unnest` and keep only the desired columns

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

gedu5 %>% 
  # Manually compute the fitted values
  nest(data = -c(Region, Country)) %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(data, ~ lm(gedu ~ poly(Year, 3), data = .x)),
         mod = map2(mod, data, augment)) %>% 
  unnest(mod) %>% 
  select(Country, Region, Year, gedu, .fitted) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = gedu, colour = Country, group = Country)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), se = FALSE) +
  geom_dl(aes(y = .fitted, label = Country), method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 1)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = "none") +
  labs(title = "Government expenditure on education, total (% of GDP)", cex.main = 2.5) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Region, 2, scales="free")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it by creating a custom `method` for `directlabels`.

Custom methods are functions with parameters `d` and `...` which return a data frame. `d` is a data frame with `x`, `y`, `groups` and a few other columns.

Create a custom method that creates the `lm` for each group. Keep the first and last values and set the `hjust` appropriately.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(directlabels)

first_last_poly3 <- function(d, ...) {
  d %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    group_modify(function(g, ...) {
      mutate(g, y = predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, 3), data = g)))
    }) %>%
    filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n())) %>%
    mutate(hjust = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1, 0))
}
```

Create the plot and use `first_last_poly3` as the `geom_dl` `method`.

```
ggplot(gedu5, aes(x = Year, y = gedu, colour = Country, group = Country)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), se = FALSE)+
  geom_point(stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Country), method = first_last_poly3) +
  labs(title = "Government expenditure on education, total (% of GDP)", cex.main = 2.5) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(.~Region, 2, scales="free")
```

[image: plot]